# How to make a part of log4net message uppercase

Tags: log4net, uppercase

I'm using AdoNetAppender to log messages. I've added %property{log4net:HostName} conversion pattern to the message parameter.

```
<parameter>
      <parameterName value="@message"/>
      <dbType value="String"/>
      <size value="4000"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="[%property{log4net:HostName}] - %message"/>
      </layout>
</parameter>
```

Output is like

[**hostname**] - foo bar.

But i want the output like

[**HOSTNAME**] - foo bar.

How can i make the hostname uppercase using conversion patterns?

Regards,

Cankut

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution suggested by Ron Grabowski is extending PatternConverter.

```
public class HostNameToUpperConverter : PatternConverter
{
    protected override void Convert(TextWriter writer, object state)
    {
        string hostName = (string)GlobalContext.Properties[LoggingEvent.HostNameProperty];
        writer.Write(hostName.ToUpper());
    }
}
```

usage in configuration file:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <converter>
          <name value="hostNameToUpper" />
          <type value="MyApplication.HostNameToUpperConverter" />
        </converter>
        <conversionPattern value="[%hostNameToUpper] - %message" />
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW (maybe someone else will find this useful), [NLog 2.0](http://nlog-project.org/) (and maybe the 1.0 Refresh) has added some layout "wrappers" that allow modification of the output of a layout.  See this [link](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Layout_renderers), towards the bottom.

Among the wrappers are uppercase, lowercase, trim whitespace, pad, and a few more.  So, you could probably define a layout that specifies the fields to be included in the output and "wrap" either whole thing or part of it in the "uppercase" wrapper.  I don't really know the exact syntax I do know that you can include layouts in other layouts so you could define a layout for "host name", wrap it in the "uppercase" wrapper, and then include that layout in the final layout.  In pseudocode (configuration file pseudocode, not code pseudocode) (very pseudo!):

```
var host=${gdc:hostname}
var uhost=${uppercase=true,inner=host}
```

Now uhost can be included in the "real" layout:

```
${datetime} | ${uhost} | ${message}
```

Or, you might do it like this:

```
${datetime} | ${uppercase=true, inner=${gdc:hostname}} | ${message}
```

Note that I have not actually tried doing this in NLog, I am just going by what is on their website.

Comment: The question is about Log4Net.